# Session duration in Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

According to this documentation, here is exists metric called session duration:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-web-track-usage#what-proportion-of-my-users-are-new

> Session duration is a metric that records the span of time between the first and last telemetry items of the session.

How can I see it?
In the portal I found option to see sessions count, but not the duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot see Session duration in metrics explorer anymore. Have to use Analytics to query/calculate it & some of the other usage metrics.

More details from MS:

> The following usage metrics are no longer automatically calculated and removed from Application Insights as we are making APM and not usage our primary focus:
>
> - session duration

Ref: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Announcements/issues/10

Comment: Better later, than never :) It is already not relevant, but thank you for the answer and link.